# Como recuperar um intervalo de meses entre duas datas?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
public function getMesesAtraso()
    {
        $data_debito= date_create($this->data_debito);
        return date_diff(date_create(now('m')), $data_debito)->format('%m');
    }
```

> Só retorna meses dentro de 2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não consegue comparar meses diretamente em anos diferentes pois o php arredonda o valor. Por exemplo, se a diferença for de 13 meses, ele irá gerar 1 ano e 1 mês. Então, quando você faz o filtro pelo `format` ele trará uma informação inesperada. Criei uma alternativa que explicarei a seguir, veja:

```
$data1 = new DateTime("2019-07-26");
$data2 = new DateTime("2020-08-26");

$diff = $data1->diff($data2); // comparação
$meses = $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m; // quantidade de meses final

echo  $meses;
```

Nesse pequeno script eu faço a comparação, depois eu multiplico por 12 a quantidade de anos de diferença e somo com a quantidade de meses.

O resultado será exatos 13 meses.

Comment: Eu não diria "burro", são apenas formas diferentes de contar o tempo. Até porque existem outros calendários em uso atualmente que dividem o ano em 13 meses: http://www.ethiopiantreasures.co.uk/pages/calendar.htm - de qualquer forma, fica o +1 :)

Comment: @hkotsubo você está certo! Não havia nem imaginado isso.